# Do Windows domain builtin groups grant the same permissions as the equivalent machine builtin groups? (eg, Performance Monitor Users)

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, groups, security-groups

I am developing a Windows service that uses [PDH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/using-the-pdh-functions-to-consume-counter-data) to query some performance counter data.

It is necessary for the service to by run by another user (ie, not the all-powerful SYSTEM).

I am aware that the user running the service must be a member of the "Performance Monitor Users" builtin group to make these calls. When I add the user to this group *on the machine running the service* (by opening lusrmgr.msc, and adding the user to the group there) the service works correctly and the PDH calls succeed. This works with local users, domain users, and Managed Service Accounts (MSA).

I would like to be able to add a domain user or MSA to the Performance Monitor Users group at the domain level, rather than at the machine level. On the Domain Controller, I see there is a list of builtin groups that includes Performance Monitor Users, but when I add my domain user or MSA to that group, it does not appear to allow my service to use PDH as I expect.

- Should the domain builtin group confer permissions like this to domain users on computers that belong to the domain, as I assumed?
- If not, what are the domain builtin groups for? How are they different than then machine-level builtin groups? In what way do they confer any permissions on their members?
- Is there some other relevant setting I'm missing to make these changes take effect?

I am not an expert in Active Directory and Windows network administration, so I may be missing something basic, I appreciate any insight.

Comment: they are equal, but usually it will then provide the access the entire domain-wide. we use this for for a non administrative user to access some monitoring data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain BULTIN groups do **NOT** confer access to domain members by default.  Domain BUILTIN groups effectively function as the equivalent of local machine groups for domain controllers.

--

You can adjust this behavior and make them work the way you describe, but I believe the correct path forward is to create *new* domain local security group.  Then, via Group Policy (either the Restricted Groups feature, or a Group Policy Preference for local groups), ensure that new group is a member of all domain members local "Performance Monitor Users" groups.

This way, you only have to change just the new group's membership to make domain-wide changes to access.

Answer (score 2):

The BUILTIN groups in Active Directory only apply to the Domain Controllers.  Adding users or groups to them doesn't apply to the workstations nor member servers. However, Group Policy Restricted Groups feature can be used to add accounts or groups to workstations and member servers via Group Policy.